# Why ul list going outside of div class="col"

Tags: html, css, html-lists

I created a `<li>` inside `<div>`, but it going outside div
i try to use clearer (from the other similar question), but it looks like doesn't work on me,
and should i use float left? because when i use `display:flex` it works

```css
.clearer {
  height           : 0;
  clear            : both;
  }
#listTopik li{
  background-color : red;
  padding          : 5px 40px 5px 40px;
  border-radius    : 5px;
  margin-left      : 10px;
  color            : white;
  }    
#listTopik {
  list-style       : none;
  display          : flex;
  }
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<div class="col-md-5">
  <h3>Topic</h3>
  <div class="col-md-5" style="width:100%">
    <ul id="listTopik">
      <li>A</li>
      <li>B</li>
      <li>C</li>
      <li>A</li>
      <li>B</li>
      <li>C</li>
      <li>A</li>
      <li>B</li>
      <li>C</li>
      <li>A</li>
      <li>B</li>
      <li>C</li>
    </ul>
    <div class="clearer"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

List outside div:

[image]

Comment: Do you want the list to stay horizontal and then wrap? Or do you want the list to be one on top of the other (vertical)?

Comment: Cause if you want them to stay horizontal, do not use display: flex, you can use class="row" on the ul tag, since you are using Bootstrap.

Comment: @Hybrid   i want to make it horizontal and wrap then loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The **ul** is overflowing from the div because of the `display:flex`, since you are using **Bootstrap**, you can actually row the lists by adding `class="row"` on the **ul** tag
and maintain responsiveness. Check the code below.

```css
div {
background: gray;
}
.list-container {
  background: blue;
}

.clearer {
  height:0;
  clear:both;
  
}
#listTopik li{
  background-color:red;
  padding:5px 40px 5px 40px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  color:white;
  margin: 5px;
}    
    
#listTopik {
  list-style:none;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-JcKb8q3iqJ61gNV9KGb8thSsNjpSL0n8PARn9HuZOnIxN0hoP+VmmDGMN5t9UJ0Z" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="col-md-7">
  <h3>Topic</h3>

    <ul id="listTopik" class="row">
      <li >A</li>
      <li>B</li>
      <li>C</li>
      <li>A</li>
      <li>B</li>
      <li>C</li>
      <li>A</li>
      <li>B</li>
      <li>C</li>
      <li>A</li>
      <li>B</li>
      <li>C</li>
    </ul>
    <div class="clearer"></div>
 
</div>
```

Comment: it works but how to make margin top or bottom for each wrap 

how to make margin between first line and second line  @Jaocampooo

Comment: @NewComes Putting a bottom and top margin to each li tag should do the trick since it will wrap depending on the screensize or div size.

Answer (score 0):

try setting parent id #listTopik to position:relative with max-width and #listTopik li to postion: absolute

Answer (score -1):

```
 <div class="col-md-5 temp">
                    <h3>Topic</h3>
                    <div class="col-md-5 temp" style="width:100%" >
                        <ul id="listTopik">
                            <li>A</li>
                            <li>B</li>
                            <li>C</li>
                            <li>A</li>
                            <li>B</li>
                            <li>C</li>
                            <li>A</li>
                            <li>B</li>
                            <li>C</li>
                            <li>A</li>
                            <li>B</li>
                            <li>C</li>
        
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                    </div>
```

```
.clearer {

     height:0;
     clear:both;
    }
#listTopik li{
            background-color:red;
            padding:5px 40px 5px 40px;
            border-radius: 5px;
            margin-left:10px;
            color:white;
            margin-bottom:10px
           
        }    
    
    #listTopik {
            list-style:none;
            flex-wrap: wrap;
            display:flex;
        }
```

Comment: An explanation would help the OP.

Comment: Lists item are overflow because of display : flex so what i have done is added display inline block for each list items what will it do is it will display number of blocks that fit in one row and others in another row and so on